# Is it possible to map a Perforce depot subpath to the workspace root folder?

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-stream

In a depot with a folder structure like:

```
depot
    subFolder1
        subSubFolder1
        subSubFolder2
    subfolder2
```

Is it possible to map just `//depot/subFolder1/...` to the workspace root on the local filesystem, so that it will contain directly `subSubFolder1` and `subSubFolder2`?

I am trying to specify the mapping for a virtual stream. I tried the following `paths` mapping, but it maps the whole depot to the root for some reason.

```
exclude ...
import+ ... //depot/subFolder1/...
```

However, a mapping like this works to map `subFolder1` to *a subfolder* in the workspace root (not *directly* to the root, which is what I want):

```
exclude ...
import+ subFolder1/... //depot/subFolder1/...
```

Note: If this isn't possible with a virtual stream, but is possible in a non-stream workspace mapping, please let me now, it's also an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you would be able to do this in a virtual stream (this is assuming that `subFolder1` is a folder in the parent stream's `Paths`, not in the depot root) with a `Remapped` line:

```
Type: virtual
Paths:
    share subFolder1/...
Remapped:
    subFolder1/... ...
```

but there is currently a (long-standing) bug that doesn't allow `Remapped` to work when the target is the root; you can remap the root to a subfolder, or any subfolder to any other subfolder, but unfortunately if you try to remap a subfolder to the root as above you get the error:

```
View '/...' must be relative and not contain leading slashes
```

so this is not presently workable.

In a classic client view it's simple:

```
View:
    //depot/subFolder1/... //your-client/...
```